# Backspace on Cygwin Screen not working for Windows 2003 Server?

Tags: cygwin, windows-server-2003, screen

I updated a working Cygwin/Screen setup on Windows 2k3 Server to Cygwin v1.7.2 and Screen 4.00.03. After updating, backspace no longer works. I haven't made any changes to my system or configuration. The Cygwin update went fine, and I don't have any custom changes in /etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a bug and is scheduled to be fixed. [See this thread on the Cygwin mailing list for details](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-04/msg00410.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this at command prompt:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash --noediting
```

Comment: Thanks, you'll want to check out the thread that I linked above. The bug was confirmed and fixed by the Cygwin team.